# Как скрыть блоки в редакторе WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть страница на сайте, в которой нужно редактировать только текст. Сейчас редактор этой страницы выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы остался только тот блок, который нужно редактировать.
Должно получиться как на этом фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Может есть такой скрипт или плагин, который может скрывать определённые блоки только в админке Wordpress?

Comment: Посредством фильтра [allowed_block_types_all](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/allowed_block_types_all/) можете привязаться либо к типу записи, либо к шаблону страницы и таким образом можете оставить только нужные блоки.

Comment: А как тогда редактировать остальное? В редакторе есть родной "режим подсветки" - юзай его.

Comment: Если это уже существующие блоки, тем более что с контентом, то наверное уточните Вашу конечную цель, потому что каким образом там будет браться остальной контент, если Вы скроете эти блоки и что это решает?

Comment: @Simon Дело в том, что сайт будет редактировать человек, который плохо разбирается в WordPress. Ему нужно редактировать только определённые блоки, а остальные блоки будут его только путать. Shortcode, блоки с html кодом и тд, он это не должен видеть. Поэтому я и хочу скрыть их

Comment: Там есть такой функционал как `Lock`. Можете залочить блоки которые не должны редактироваться, например [How to lock blocks and templates](https://fullsiteediting.com/how-to-lock-blocks-and-templates/). Определенным пользователям так же можно запретить "разблокировать" блоки.

Comment: @Simon Но shortcode можно редактировать даже если они залочены, html код тоже можно редактировать даже если он залочен